# Displaying an error message in Do/while loop C#

Tags: c#

I am a complete beginner to c# and I am trying to create a very simple login program. I have the following code:

```
do
  {
   AdvancedUtilities.TyperwriterTextEffect("Please create a password for your account (8-10 characters): ");
   AccountPassword = Console.ReadLine();
   _accountPassword = AccountPassword;
  } while (_accountPassword.Length < 8 && _accountPassword.Length >= 10);
```

However, every time the input doesn't meet the while loop conditions, the same message will show again

> "Please create a password for your account (8-10 characters)"

How can i make it so that i show an error message like

> "Please try again: "

instead of repeating the original one?

Comment: Move the current message outside of the loop and create a condition inside the loop that displays your desired message if the password doesn't meet the condition criteria

Comment: Also, a side-note: can you think of a time when a number is less than 8 and also greater than or equal to 10?

Comment: And why are you trying to prevent password being too long? A password can never be too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two messages.

```
AdvancedUtilities.TyperwriterTextEffect("Please create a password for your account (8-10 characters): ");
while (true)
{
    AccountPassword = Console.ReadLine();
    _accountPassword = AccountPassword;
    if (_accountPassword.Length >= 8 && _accountPassword.Length < 10) break;
    AdvancedUtilities.TyperwriterTextEffect("Please try again: ");
}
```

Note: There are ways to write this without using `while(true)` but to me this is the clearest way that avoids code duplication. When you use `while(true)` it signals to anyone reading your code to look for the `break` and `continue` flow of control keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the message in a variable and change the variable after you show it the first time.

The length cannot be simultaneously less than 8 AND greater than 10 characters in length so I only used your condition that made sense.

```
    string message = "Please create a password for your account (8-10 characters): ";
    
    do
    {
        AdvancedUtilities.TyperwriterTextEffect(message);
        AccountPassword = Console.ReadLine();
        _accountPassword = AccountPassword;

        message = "Please try again";
    } while (_accountPassword.Length < 8);
```

Comment: This is a clever way of solving the problem while still using a do/while loop, is clear to read, and avoids code duplication.